# why use distinct function was different in sql Query result and Linq result?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

this is my raw data

[image]

LINQ code

```
   public PartialViewResult Menu()
        {
            IEnumerable<string> categories = repository.Products
                        .Select(x => x.Category)
                        .Distinct();    
            return PartialView(categories.Distinct());
        }
```

LINQ result

[image]

Why use distinct function , LINQ have the different result

Comment: That SQL Query should only return category, based on what you're entered.  I don't believe the results match your query.

Comment: Why select distinct [Category]  in your SQL returning so many other columns, you didn't put the actual query which you run.

Comment: And one `Soccer` has a space behind it `Soccer `

Comment: Side-note: instead of storing the category as string in your product table redundantly you should have a foreign-key here to another table `Category`. >> [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 2):

There are sometimes spaces at the end of the category. You should not store them. You could fix it in the SELECT query with `Trim`:

```
IEnumerable<string> categories = repository.Products
                    .Select(x => x.Category.Trim())
                    .Distinct();
```

But instead of storing the category as string in your product table redundantly you should have a foreign-key here to another table `Category` >> [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)